# How to make maximum utilization of the screen space in my web page generated from Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I've managed to dowload and setup Jekyll with `minima` theme to log my daily task updates in my blog. Currently it looks like below

[image]

I wanted to make the editable content full screen, so that I have more space in the page for writing really long blog posts. I located the file `_site/assets/main.css` and trying modifying the container

The content of the file is as below. I'm not an expert at SaaS and styling the pages, but I tried to modify the `.container` attribute to increase the `.padding` and `.margin` to random high values and did a `jekyll build` after that and on still loading the page, it wasn't reflecting the changes made.

SO how do I make this page to make maximum utility of the screen space?

```
/**
 * Reset some basic elements
 */
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, blockquote, pre, hr,
dl, dd, ol, ul, figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

/**
 * Basic styling
 */
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  color: #111;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
  -o-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
  font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;
  font-kerning: normal;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column; }

/**
 * Set `margin-bottom` to maintain vertical rhythm
 */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, blockquote, pre,
ul, ol, dl, figure,
.highlight {
  margin-bottom: 15px; }

/**
 * `main` element
 */
main {
  display: block;
  /* Default value of `display` of `main` element is 'inline' in IE 11. */ }

/**
 * Images
 */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle; }

/**
 * Figures
 */
figure > img {
  display: block; }

figcaption {
  font-size: 14px; }

/**
 * Lists
 */
ul, ol {
  margin-left: 30px; }

li > ul,
li > ol {
  margin-bottom: 0; }

/**
 * Headings
 */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 400; }

/**
 * Links
 */
a {
  color: #2a7ae2;
  text-decoration: none; }
  a:visited {
    color: #1756a9; }
  a:hover {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: underline; }
  .social-media-list a:hover {
    text-decoration: none; }
    .social-media-list a:hover .username {
      text-decoration: underline; }

/**
 * Blockquotes
 */
blockquote {
  color: #828282;
  border-left: 4px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-style: italic; }
  blockquote > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; }

/**
 * Code formatting
 */
pre,
code {
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eef; }

code {
  padding: 1px 5px; }

pre {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  overflow-x: auto; }
  pre > code {
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0; }

/**
 * Wrapper
 */
.wrapper {
  max-width: -webkit-calc(800px - (30px * 2));
  max-width: calc(800px - (30px * 2));
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .wrapper {
      max-width: -webkit-calc(800px - (30px));
      max-width: calc(800px - (30px));
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px; } }

/**
 * Clearfix
 */
.wrapper:after, .footer-col-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }

/**
 * Icons
 */
.svg-icon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  fill: #828282;
  padding-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: text-top; }

.social-media-list li + li {
  padding-top: 5px; }

/**
 * Tables
 */
table {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8; }
  table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7; }
  table th, table td {
    padding: 10px 15px; }
  table th {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom-color: #c9c9c9; }
  table td {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8; }

/**
 * Site header
 */
.site-header {
  border-top: 5px solid #424242;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  min-height: 55.95px;
  position: relative; }

.site-title {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 54px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: left; }
  .site-title, .site-title:visited {
    color: #424242; }

.site-nav {
  float: right;
  line-height: 54px; }
  .site-nav .nav-trigger {
    display: none; }
  .site-nav .menu-icon {
    display: none; }
  .site-nav .page-link {
    color: #111;
    line-height: 1.5; }
    .site-nav .page-link:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 20px; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .site-nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 9px;
      right: 15px;
      background-color: #fdfdfd;
      border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: right; }
      .site-nav label[for="nav-trigger"] {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;
        z-index: 2;
        cursor: pointer; }
      .site-nav .menu-icon {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        width: 36px;
        height: 26px;
        line-height: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-align: center; }
        .site-nav .menu-icon > svg {
          fill: #424242; }
      .site-nav input ~ .trigger {
        clear: both;
        display: none; }
      .site-nav input:checked ~ .trigger {
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 5px; }
      .site-nav .page-link {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin-left: 20px; }
        .site-nav .page-link:not(:last-child) {
          margin-right: 0; } }

/**
 * Site footer
 */
.site-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding: 30px 0; }

.footer-heading {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px; }

.contact-list,
.social-media-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0; }

.footer-col-wrapper {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #828282;
  margin-left: -15px; }

.footer-col {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px; }

.footer-col-1 {
  width: -webkit-calc(35% - (30px / 2));
  width: calc(35% - (30px / 2)); }

.footer-col-2 {
  width: -webkit-calc(20% - (30px / 2));
  width: calc(20% - (30px / 2)); }

.footer-col-3 {
  width: -webkit-calc(45% - (30px / 2));
  width: calc(45% - (30px / 2)); }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .footer-col-1,
  .footer-col-2 {
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - (30px / 2));
    width: calc(50% - (30px / 2)); }

  .footer-col-3 {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - (30px / 2));
    width: calc(100% - (30px / 2)); } }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .footer-col {
    float: none;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - (30px / 2));
    width: calc(100% - (30px / 2)); } }
/**
 * Page content
 */
.page-content {
  padding: 30px 0;
  flex: 1; }

.page-heading {
  font-size: 32px; }

.post-list-heading {
  font-size: 28px; }

.post-list {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none; }
  .post-list > li {
    margin-bottom: 30px; }

.post-meta {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #828282; }

.post-link {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px; }

/**
 * Posts
 */
.post-header {
  margin-bottom: 30px; }

.post-title {
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .post-title {
      font-size: 36px; } }

.post-content {
  margin-bottom: 30px; }
  .post-content h2 {
    font-size: 32px; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .post-content h2 {
        font-size: 28px; } }
  .post-content h3 {
    font-size: 26px; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .post-content h3 {
        font-size: 22px; } }
  .post-content h4 {
    font-size: 20px; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .post-content h4 {
        font-size: 18px; } }

/**
 * Syntax highlighting styles
 */
.highlight {
  background: #fff; }
  .highlighter-rouge .highlight {
    background: #eef; }
  .highlight .c {
    color: #998;
    font-style: italic; }
  .highlight .err {
    color: #a61717;
    background-color: #e3d2d2; }
  .highlight .k {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .o {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .cm {
    color: #998;
    font-style: italic; }
  .highlight .cp {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .c1 {
    color: #998;
    font-style: italic; }
  .highlight .cs {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic; }
  .highlight .gd {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fdd; }
  .highlight .gd .x {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #faa; }
  .highlight .ge {
    font-style: italic; }
  .highlight .gr {
    color: #a00; }
  .highlight .gh {
    color: #999; }
  .highlight .gi {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #dfd; }
  .highlight .gi .x {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #afa; }
  .highlight .go {
    color: #888; }
  .highlight .gp {
    color: #555; }
  .highlight .gs {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .gu {
    color: #aaa; }
  .highlight .gt {
    color: #a00; }
  .highlight .kc {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .kd {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .kp {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .kr {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .kt {
    color: #458;
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .m {
    color: #099; }
  .highlight .s {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .na {
    color: #008080; }
  .highlight .nb {
    color: #0086B3; }
  .highlight .nc {
    color: #458;
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .no {
    color: #008080; }
  .highlight .ni {
    color: #800080; }
  .highlight .ne {
    color: #900;
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .nf {
    color: #900;
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .nn {
    color: #555; }
  .highlight .nt {
    color: #000080; }
  .highlight .nv {
    color: #008080; }
  .highlight .ow {
    font-weight: bold; }
  .highlight .w {
    color: #bbb; }
  .highlight .mf {
    color: #099; }
  .highlight .mh {
    color: #099; }
  .highlight .mi {
    color: #099; }
  .highlight .mo {
    color: #099; }
  .highlight .sb {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .sc {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .sd {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .s2 {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .se {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .sh {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .si {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .sx {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .sr {
    color: #009926; }
  .highlight .s1 {
    color: #d14; }
  .highlight .ss {
    color: #990073; }
  .highlight .bp {
    color: #999; }
  .highlight .vc {
    color: #008080; }
  .highlight .vg {
    color: #008080; }
  .highlight .vi {
    color: #008080; }
  .highlight .il {
    color: #099; }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Editing inside **_site** folder is not the way to go. This is the Jekyll's generated code and it's overwritten each time you do a `jekyll build` or `jekyll serve`.

In order to facilitate beginners job, jekyll is cleverly hiding _layouts, _includes, _sass and assets in theme's gem files.

But where are they hidden ? Just do a `bundle show minima` and you obtain a path like *~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minima-2.5.0/assets*.

If you want to change something in those files, just copy them to your site root and these copies will be used instead of gem files.

In your case, you just have to copy /path/to/gem/**assets/main.scss** to **assets/main.scss** and edit it like this :

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---
$content-width: 100%;

@import "minima";
```

Your website is now full width (with margins, but it better for readability).

If you want to go further, you can have a look in the _sass folder.

And yes, [jekyll's themes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/) are *a pain in the interwoo*.

Comment: Great stuff! it worked! Could you point me a link where I can play with other saas variables like `content-width`?

Comment: Also could you just touch upon how I can modify the `.css` styling like font and other stuff from this file? E.g. I want to reduce the font size across the pages?

Comment: Everything is in `bundle show minima`/_sass/ folder. You can copy this folder a your root and hack it.

Answer (score 2):

Add `$content-width` to the [_sass/minima/custom-variables.scss](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_sass/minima/custom-variables.scss) file, in current (`Aug 2021`) version of [jekyll/minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) theme:

```
$content-width:    100%;
```

Notes

- We can change `100%` to some other value as needed, like: `90%`, `1920px`
- The `custom-variables.scss` is designed to add customized values